# Using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF, is there a way to avoid exposing my Bing API Key?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, maps, bing

Using only the map, there is no reason I should even use an API Key. Bing allow using a session key for this purpose.
But obtaining a session key and using it generates an invalid key tooltip over the map.
I don't even want to use Bing map, I just use the control to use OpenStreetMap tiles in it...

```
        private void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myMap.CredentialsProvider.GetCredentials((c) =>
            {
                var sessionKey = c.ApplicationId;
                myMap.CredentialsProvider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider(sessionKey);
            });
        }
```

This code works to obtaining a session key and setting it. But it won't work in the control.

Comment: You could use an alternative map control.

Comment: @Clemens Actually, I tried using yours (I think), and I couldn't get it to work in my context. XAML-Map Control.
Can you provide a simple example, with inline configuration for Open Street Map?